# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16 October 2016" (at offset 3)

Tags: java, android

I try to convert date format from "16 October 2016" to "2016-10-16 00:00:00" and vice versa. the first format is used to display on the app, and the second one is to send to sql database. I use the following code,

```
convertedBirthdate = Helper.convertDateFormat(birthdate,
                    "d mmmm yyyy", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

---

```
public static String convertDateFormat(String dateTime, String previousFormat,
                                    String destinationFormat) {

        String formattedDateTime = null;

        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(previousFormat);
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateTime);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(destinationFormat);
            formattedDateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedDateTime;

    }
```

but i got the following error exception,

```
10-16 18:34:45.023 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "16 Oktober 2016" (at offset 3)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at id.co.impilo.patient.helper.Helper.convertDateFormat(Helper.java:171)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at id.co.impilo.patient.activities.ActivityAddPatient.callAddPatientAPI(ActivityAddPatient.java:832)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at id.co.impilo.patient.activities.ActivityAddPatient.addPatient(ActivityAddPatient.java:302)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at id.co.impilo.patient.activities.ActivityAddPatient_ViewBinding$4.doClick(ActivityAddPatient_ViewBinding.java:87)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
10-16 18:34:45.028 15313-15313/id.co.impilo.patient W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Probably a Locale problem

Comment: Don't you think it's odd that you're using the same character for _month_ and _minute_? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Oktober is not true! change it to October :)

Comment: By the way, SQLite provides its own date formatting features. Converting to the display via Java shouldn't be necessary

Comment: For probably the 157th time: Month is `M`, not `m`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder M At first i used M, but it does not work.

Comment: i have found the problem, i need to add Locale.getDefault() as @cricket_007 said. thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear. You'll also want to fix the formats as the others stated

Comment: That's why you use `yyyy-MM-dd` for your database and populate UI based on your data set. So you never ever convert *from* "16 Oktober 2016". Only from machine readable to human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I edit my code by adding Locale.getDefault() to solve the issue,

```
public static String convertDateFormat(String dateTime, String previousFormat,
                                    String destinationFormat) {

        String formattedDateTime = null;

        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(previousFormat, Locale.getDefault());
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateTime);
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(destinationFormat, Locale.getDefault());
            formattedDateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedDateTime;

    }
```